# How can I download or export PDF in PHP from CUrl and output to VUE JS?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

This is the output of response with my code using CURL
I want to know what will I use to response it to JSON if its possible.
or and other solution for this.

[image: PDF RESPONSE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an iframe to show the PDF content.

In your template:

```
<iframe
  v-if="pdf"
  :src="`${pdf}`"
  width="100%"
>
  'This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it:' <a :href="`your link to the pdf`" >'Download PDF'</a>
</iframe>
```

In your script:

```
methods: {
    previewPDFReport () {
      this.pdf = null
      axios.get('your link to the pdf')
        .then(res => res.data)
        .then(data => {
          let blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' })
          let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
          this.pdf = url
        })
    }
}
```